# how to retrieve text from text are with php on same page

Tags: php, html

I have a text-area, in which I need some text.

I simply need to get that text to be echoed out with PHP, while on the *same* page

This is my code so far:

```
<body>
    <br>
    <h1>Charles Dickens</h1>
    <form action="Charles Dickens.php" method="GET">
        <hr/>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="textTest">This a is the text Testing area.</textarea>
        <hr/>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <?php 
        $textTest = $_GET['textTest'];
        echo $textTest;
    ?>

</body>
```

for some reason it's give me an "undefined error", though the variable is defined:

```
textTest is undefined.
```

Comment: it says because textTest has not value set yet.

Comment: try it: if(isset($_GET['textTest']))
{
 echo $_GET['textTest']
}

Comment: @AhmadHassan this seems to just get rid of the error but not echo out my text

Comment: mate! it will echo when you submit the form on the same page

Comment: @AhmadHassan a! Indeed, i was trying to get it instantly without submitting

Comment: if you want it without submitting then use js instead php

Comment: your file name (Charles Dickens.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your file name as well:

- it should be without space or with hyphens

here you can like this, but you need to submit a form:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["textTest"]){
    echo $_GET["textTest"];
    }
?>
```

If you don't want to submit form try it:

```
<script>
    $('#text-id').keypress(function() {
        var value = this.value;
        console.log(value);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Progrock right

Comment: Word delination is useful.  Filenames can contain spaces, spaces can be unsafe in URLS, use an encoded space to represent one.  And underscores can also present usabliity issues - think interpreting an underlined link containing an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the get variable is still defined:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["textTest"]){
    echo $_GET["textTest"];
}
?>
```

or add `?textTest=the%20text` to the uri ;)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment for this...

Try doing

```
var_dump($_GET['textTest'])
```

Also add what Ahmad Hassan said, as before you submit the form the varible is undefined

```
if(isset($_GET['textTest'])) { echo $_GET['textTest'] }
```